# What are the valid Style Format Strings for a Reporting Services [SSRS] Expression?

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

I am trying to figure out the style string for the Format(Expression as Object, Style as String) function in a Reporting Services expression.

I can't find where these style format strings are documented!

Specifically I am trying to format a Price field to be always 2 decimal places.

ie 1.5 formats to $1.50

Comment: The answers are good for your specific question, but in general, you should avoid using the `=Format()` function, and instead set the format on the textbox or placeholder. Those will take the same format strings as `Format()` but exports will preserve the value of the number, not convert it to a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180160/ssrs-2005-number-formating-int-and-double-within-one-field

Comment: Yes, we probably wouldn't need the `Format()` function if SSRS supported conditional expressions for field number formats.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Format with *Currency* format string

```
=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "C")
```

It will give you 2 decimal places with "$" prefixed.

You can find other format strings on MSDN: [Adding Style and Formatting to a ReportViewer Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080(VS.80).aspx)

***Note***: The MSDN article has been archived to the "VS2005_General" document, which is no longer directly accessible online. Here is the excerpt of the formatting strings referenced:

> **Formatting Numbers**
>
> The following table lists common .NET Framework number formatting
>   strings.
>
> **Format string, Name**
>
> C or c Currency
>
> D or d Decimal
>
> E or e Scientific
>
> F or f Fixed-point
>
> G or g General
>
> N or n Number
>
> P or p Percentage
>
> R or r Round-trip
>
> X or x Hexadecimal
>
> You can modify many of the format strings to include a precision
>   specifier that defines the number of digits to the right of the
>
> decimal point. For example, a formatting string of D0 formats the
>   number so that it has no digits after the decimal point. You
>
> can also use custom formatting strings, for example, #,###.
>
> **Formatting Dates**
>
> The following table lists common .NET Framework date formatting
>   strings.
>
> **Format string, Name**
>
> d Short date
>
> D Long date
>
> t Short time
>
> T Long time
>
> f Full date/time (short time)
>
> F Full date/time (long time)
>
> g General date/time (short time)
>
> G General date/time (long time)
>
> M or m Month day
>
> R or r RFC1123 pattern
>
> Y or y Year month
>
> You can also a use custom formatting strings; for example, dd/MM/yy.
>   For more information about .NET Framework
>   formatting strings, see Formatting Types.

Comment: This is the correct answer to my specific question... I had tried that previously but I also had an error in my code, I put a CStr() inside of the Format function. I had to change Format(CStr(Fields!Price.Value), "C") to CStr(Format(Fields!Price.Value, "C"))

Comment: @Jon: Are you using "Cstr()" to append the value of formatted price to another string?

Comment: NB: If you want your local currency, make sure you set the Language property of the Report itself appropriately, e.g. if you have the report's Language set to "en-GB", then the currency formatting string "C" will give you £ rather than $.

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned, you can use:

```
=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "C")
```

A digit after the "C" will specify precision:

```
=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "C0")
=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "C1")
```

You can also use [Excel-style masks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) like this:

```
=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "#,##0.00")
```

Haven't tested the last one, but there's the idea. Also works with dates:

```
=Format(Fields!Date.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Thanks Peter!  I needed to display up to 4 places after the decimal, so I was able to use the mask you suggested. =Format(Fields!rate.Value, "$###,###,##0.00##")

Answer (score 4):

You can set TextBox properties for setting negative number display and decimal places settings.

1. Right-click the cell and then click Text Box Properties.
2. Select Number, and in the Category field, click Currency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the schema at 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd

Search for xsd:complexType name="StyleType"

This will list out all the possible Styles you can use.

Specific to your question however, you can use the Format style.

> Format
>
> ```
> Specify the data format to use for values that appear in the textbox.
> ```
>
> Valid values include Default, Number,
>   Date, Time, Percentage, and Currency.

Link to MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251684(VS.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for good links. I'm not using the Format() function, but putting the codes into the "Number -> Format" textbox at design-time instead, and could not find the list of codes anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Give a Format String value of C2 for the value's properties as shown in figure below.

[image]