# SSRS 2005 Number formatting int and double within one field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using `SSRS 2005`. The issue is I would like to place, in numbers so if number is 23455 it should be displayed as 23,455 I know how to do this I have two data types in this field int and double. What I did to accommodate it is changed the numbers to strings but if I extract them to Excel they show green triangle.

To eliminate green triangle in Excel I used `CDEC()` function which converts the string to number by doing this I loose , in the numbers.

I was wondering if it is even possible to place a comma within the field which has two different datatypes i.e. double and int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are not your friends! Don't convert numbers to strings.

You should set the format of your cells (textboxes or placeholders) to include the comma. Right click on a text box or placeholder to get the properties dialog. Use the Number pane to format. (You can set this exact same setting in the properties pane as well.

Using these will let the number stay a number in the cell, and will export the formatting to Excel without the conversion to a string.

[image: SSRS Textbox Property Dialog]
[image: SSRS PRoperties Pane]