# Convert into specific format. $ sign and Phone number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

In SQL I have data in this format 3M/3M. I would like to convert this data into this format $3M/$3M. 
Also In SQL I have phone number in this format 123456781. I would like to convert this data into this phone format (123)-456-7891.

How can I convert it?
Should I use CAST or CONVERT function?

CORRECTION:

Yes, I'd to display them in the said format in my SELECT query. 
3M/3M is just an example of data in SQL. The column name Money has that type of data and I'd like to convert it to $3M/$3M etc...

The same with the phone number. I have column name PhoneNumber and it contains data in this format 1234567891 and I'd like to conver it to (123)-456-7891 etc... There are many phone numbers...

Comment: I think you mean to display them in that format?

Comment: Edited your post and removed the tags `caste,convert`. I think those are not needed.

Comment: Why do you need to format these in SQL Server? It is going to be much more efficient to apply formatting where you actually *display* the data - and languages like C# have much richer formatting options than T-SQL anyway.

Comment: For base data, you shouldn't ever _store_ it formatted, especially in the case where you're dealing with multiple cultures, and will need to display data in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to display them in the said format in your `SELECT` query. Then you can do like below using `LEFT() or RIGHT()` function and concatenate the `$` character.

```
select '$' + left('3M/3M',2) + '/$' + right('3M/3M',2);
```

Results in `$3M/$3M`

The Phone Number

```
select '('+ left('123456781',3) + ')-'+
right(left('123456781',6),3)+'-'+right('123456781',3)
```

Results in `(123)-456-781`

Answer (score 0):

You can also format phone number as below:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING ('123456781', 0, 0) + '(' +  
SUBSTRING ('123456781', 1, 3) + ')-' + 
SUBSTRING('123456781', 4, 3) + '-' + 
SUBSTRING('123456781', 7, 4)
```

The result:

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1) You could format those strings easily on the client or in report. For example, Reporting Services has a [Format property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189363(v=sql.90).aspx) for textbox and, also, has a [Format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922506/what-are-the-valid-style-format-strings-for-a-reporting-services-ssrs-expressi).

2) You could format strings in SQL Server only if you don't have any options (see #1) thus:

```
SELECT '(' + STUFF(STUFF('1234567891', 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, ')-') AS Val1

SELECT '$' + REPLACE('3M/3M', '/', '/$') AS Val2

/*
Val1
--------------
(123)-456-7891

Val2
--------------
$3M/$3M
*/

SELECT FORMAT(1234567891, '(###)-###-####') AS Val3 -- SQL Server 2012+
/*
Val3
--------------
(123)-456-7891
*/
```