# How to convert numeric value into money value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to convert following DB return value as 1000.1467 as 1,000.15 and if the return value is null i want to display '-' in SSRS report.Please any one advice how to write expression for this condition.

Comment: use IIF() in SSRS expression, and set the textbox property `FORMAT` to `C` for currency

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
  select isnull(convert(varchar(10),cast(round(1000.1467,2) as money),-1),'-')
```

Comment: i want to convert this in my report not in SQL query :(.Can you please let me know how to write this is in report.

Comment: check out this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922506/what-are-the-valid-style-format-strings-for-a-reporting-services-ssrs-expressi