# Use comma for decimals and period for thousands rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm using Report Viewer Control (rdlc) to generate reports. One of my columns represent a decimal value from a SQL database, for example:

```
5199.9800
```

and at the end of this column, all the amounts are summed. So, the amounts rows are represented this way:

```
 =Fields!DEBIT.Value
```

And the total row is represented this way:

```
 =Sum(CDbl(Fields!DEBIT.Value), "dtsItems")
```

Currently all the values are formatted in the standard way, using comma for thousands and period for decimals like this:

```
  5,199.98
```

but i need to format it the opposite way: using period for thousands and comma for decimals, like this:

```
   5.199,98
```

I've been searching for a way to do it with an expression or just changing the TextBox properties in the rdlc file, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using Excel style masks? It would be something like this:

```
=Format(CDbl(Fields!DEBIT.Value), "#.###,##")
```

Or you can convert it to a string and use the all the goodness of a string.format, but you lose sorting.

Another related solution:
[What are the valid Style Format Strings for a Reporting Services [SSRS] Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922506/what-are-the-valid-style-format-strings-for-a-reporting-services-ssrs-expressi)

Answer (score 0):

First select object with expression, usually text box and in properties find property Format and enter this: **#,0.00;(#,0.00)**
Somewhere below format find Language property and set to **hr-HR** (this is for Croatia Republic). That's all... Works for me!