# Specific format number in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm trying to format expression which as result holds numerical value.
This value should be format/displayed like for example **12.456,78**
I've tryed to set custom format **#.###,##** number is still displyed like **12,456.78**

Is there any way to set format just as I want?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312120/use-comma-for-decimals-and-period-for-thousands-rdlc-report), but no accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to force a specific culture's number formats? The `String.Format()` function will use the current culture for thousands separator and decimal point?

You can override items of the `NumberFormatInfo`, however you will have to embed this as custom code in your report. As in

```
<expression>=Code.OverrideNumberFormat(Fields!MyNumber.Value)

Public String OverrideNumberFormat(Float number) As String
Begin
....
End Function
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) article with an example of overriding a cultures `NumberFormatInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found solution.

- first select object with expression, usually text box and in properties find property ***Format*** and enter this: **#,0.00;(#,0.00)**
- somewhere below format find ***Language*** property and set to **hr-HR** (this is for Croatia Republic). That's all...